# Why use prevState in React setState function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Please tell me what different using prevState and using Array.filter.

```
// components is an array that has object {key: string, item: {}}
const defaultValue = [
  {
    key: 'a',
    item: {},
  },
  {
    key: 'b',
    item: {},
  },
  {
    key: 'c',
    item: {},
  }
];
const [components, setComponent] =  React.useState(defaultValue);

// using prevState
setComponents(prevState => prevState.filter(item => item.key !== 'b'));

// using Array. filter
setComponents(components.filter(item => item.key !== 'b')))
```

As a result, `using Array.filter`  is not fine working.
I wondered. The reason is Array.filter returns a new array.

Please tell me what different using prevState and using Array.filter

Comment: where is array.concat

Comment: I missed. Not concat

Comment: You have a typo in `fillter` which should be `filter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here,

```
setComponents(components.fillter(item => item.key !== 'b')))
                         // ^ typo
```

try something like this,

```
setComponents(components.concat(
  components.filter(item => item.key !== 'b'))
))
```